# Problem while installing virtualenvwrapper with pyenv + pipx

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

I'm trying to install `virtualenvwrapper` (not `pyenv-virtualenvwrapper`) in my macOS (using zsh). I'm using `pyenv` to mange multiple python versions and [`pipx`](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) to install CLI stuff.

I'm using Python 3.8.1

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.17
* 3.8.1 (set by /Users/my_user/.pyenv/version)
```

I installed virtualenvwrapper with pipx

```
$ pipx install virtualenvwrapper

$ pipx list
venvs are in /Users/my_user/.local/pipx/venvs
apps are exposed on your $PATH at /Users/my_user/.local/bin
   package sshuttle 0.78.5, Python 3.8.1
    - sshuttle
   package virtualenv 20.0.15, Python 3.8.1
    - virtualenv
   package virtualenvwrapper 4.8.4, Python 3.8.1
    - virtualenvwrapper.sh
    - virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

and I inserted in my `.zshrc` the following lines:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /Users/my_user/.local/pipx/venvs/virtualenvwrapper/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
```

But when I launch the shell I get the following error:

```
/Users/my_user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Users/my_user/.pyenv/shims/python and that PATH is
set properly.
$
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed specifying a specific `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` without pointing to the shim

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Users/my_user/.local/pipx/venvs/virtualenvwrapper/bin/python3.8
source /Users/my_user/.local/pipx/venvs/virtualenvwrapper/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```